# NativeScript learning roadmap?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I using angular 2 for my production project, but now I want to learn NativeScript for myself?

Can anybody helps me with learning roadmap?

Comment: Tutorial recommendation questions are expressly off-topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coming from an Angular-2 development I guess that you will want to learn **NativeScrpt + Angular-2** and not **NativeScript Core** (there are some major differences). If that is the case I recommend going through [this tutorial](http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/tutorial/ng-chapter-1.html) step by step. You will need installed Node.js(recommended 6.9.2 at this moment), NativeScript (latest), TypeScript.